# variable dentro de un echo

Tags: php, php7, php5, cakephp

Tengo un `echo' ';`
el cual contiene codigo html,intento ponerle una variable php dentro de ese `echo'"".$saludos.""';`pero en vez de imprimirme el valor que contiene esa variable, me imprime su nombre, como puedo hacer para que me imprima el valor de la variable.
Muchas gracias por su paciencia, saludos.

Comment: En PHP si encierras una variable en comillas dobles, te imprimirá correctamente el valor de la misma, por ejemplo, algo así funcionará sin problemas: `$laVariable="una variable"; echo "Soy contenido de $laVariable";`

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Bobloquito para imprimir variables en dentro de cadenas tienes que hacer como si lo hicieras en JavaScript es lo que piensa mi cabeza.

Si en JavaScript seria:

```
var variable = 'de prueba';
console.log('Esto es un texto '+ variable +'.';
```

En PHP seria lo siguiente:

```
$variable = 'de prueba';
echo 'Esto es un texto '.$variable.'.';
```

Si te das cuenta estoy poniendo la variable dentro de la cadena de texto ya que  termina con un punto que allí podrías poner cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: Si me funciono, muchas gracias :-)

Comment: recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta @Bobloquito